# optimal algorithm strategy for a 2 player game

Tags: algorithm

This is a question I came across in one of the online coding contests:

This is a 2 player game . There are two breeds of warriors to start off "**A**" and "**B**". 
Given **n** cities and each city **i** has **w[i]** number of warriors (which can be either of the breed A or B) . Each warrior **j** in a city has a strength **S[j]** .

The first player has to choose a breed of warrior . The second player gets the other breed .In his turn , the player must choose a city and a warrior in that city of his choosen breed.

One player will choose a breed of warrior and a city to start the game . This warrior will kill every other warrior of the city with less strength than him ***irrespective of the breed***. At the end he will die. Next , the second player will choose another city and breed and do the same. This continues until there are no more moves left.

The first player has to decide which breed of warrior to choose so that he wins or if there is no way for him to win if his opponent plays optimally.

What is the optimal algorithm strategy for the first player to win.

Example -

let there be one city (C1) with 2 warriors- **W1** of strength **10** and breed **A** , W2 of strength **15** and breed **B**.

The first player will chose the breed B whose warrior will kill the other warrior and hence the second player won't have any warrior to choose from.

Comment: You say that players choose a breed and city, but then talk about "this warrior" killing other warriors as if the players had chosen specific warriors. Could you specify the problem more precisely?

Comment: Sorry my bad. The first player has to choose a breed of warrior . The second player gets the other breed .In his turn , the player must choose a city and a warrior in that city of his choosen breed..

Comment: What happens if the player1 chooses the weaker warrior in the example? The warrior you've chosen dies for sure at the end of the turn and the stronger ones live? Are there multiple warriors of the same breed and how do they act(do they fight their breed)? If they do what is the purpose of "breed"?

Comment: yeah, there can be multiple players of the same breed . You have to choose a breed in such a way so that playing optimally you will win the game.

Comment: Problem is not clear. More rules are needed to be clarified.

Comment: Did the question come with problem-size limits? If this is a programming problem (rather than a math problem), then the solution will involve either a search or dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

From your description the optimal solution is easy.
For each warrior in a city pick the highest power warrior.
Count the top warriors for each city and whatever breed has the best warriors will win.